# Inline block in Firefox does not scale down to contents

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have two columns, both 50% of the screen-width. The left column is filled with text, the right column has an image that scales to the height of the text. Another image is placed over this first image, positioned in the bottom right corner. Even if the screen-width exceeds the image-width (and whitespace appears to the right of the image), the second image should stay aligned to the bottom right corner of the first one.

The setup you can see in the code below works in browsers other than Firefox. In Firefox, the second image is positioned as far right as possible, up to the original width of the first image. I think I've narrowed it down to the 100% height I give `.image div`, if I use a fixed height (i.e. 400px), the second image is aligned correctly. I need the percentage height though, to let the first image scale to the text height.

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.image div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image div:after {
  content: url("https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/6/67/Marvin_the_martian.jpg");
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
}

.image>div>img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vel enim vulputate, luctus dolor vel, efficitur ante. Maecenas eget massa eu mi varius posuere vel mattis ante. Cras non fermentum sapien. Nunc sollicitudin nisi a posuere commodo. Fusce
      tincidunt mi velit, in hendrerit dolor cursus et. Nam laoreet laoreet varius. Aliquam ut elit at elit ultricies iaculis vitae at purus. Pellentesque massa mi, ultricies elementum consequat sit amet, aliquam vitae sem. Nulla tempus nec augue non
      lacinia. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed quis rhoncus urna, lobortis bibendum sapien. Morbi accumsan commodo malesuada. Praesent porta tortor sed tristique dignissim. Maecenas et urna sit amet tortor semper commodo at vitae lectus. Nullam
      imperdiet viverra sem, pellentesque sagittis ipsum pellentesque a. Mauris rutrum nunc id lectus commodo rhoncus.</p>

    <p>Etiam mollis massa id lorem rhoncus venenatis. Donec lacinia orci lacus, ac auctor augue vehicula vitae. Cras dignissim, augue vitae hendrerit cursus, enim velit lacinia tellus, sit amet sollicitudin dui mauris eget tortor. Donec eu nulla a est interdum
      aliquet. Praesent et lectus interdum, malesuada felis sed, sagittis est. Pellentesque in accumsan diam. Nam tristique porttitor tortor. In rutrum tellus nisi, id condimentum tellus fringilla ut.</p>
    <p>Etiam mollis massa id lorem rhoncus venenatis. Donec lacinia orci lacus, ac auctor augue vehicula vitae. Cras dignissim, augue vitae hendrerit cursus, enim velit lacinia tellus, sit amet sollicitudin dui mauris eget tortor. Donec eu nulla a est interdum
      aliquet. Praesent et lectus interdum, malesuada felis sed, sagittis est. Pellentesque in accumsan diam. Nam tristique porttitor tortor. In rutrum tellus nisi, id condimentum tellus fringilla ut.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <div>
      <img src="https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/saturn.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see how it works in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NabQWV).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Relevant code belongs directly into your question, not only on external sites. Please edit your question in that regard.

Comment: it seems to be a FF  bug. when image is resized down,  area being used is somehow not updated .... Maybe a workaround with flex would do ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yzXEpO

Comment: @G-Cyr this comes really close (even though the image doesn't scale to the height of the text column, but keeps its own size. I could live with that, though). But unfortunately I do need to support Internet Explorer as well. Flex and cover-size are only marginally supported, and without cover-size the image deforms when scaling to smaller sizes. I think I'd rather not show the second image in Firefox (as it is cosmetic) until the bug is (hopefully) fixed, seeing as this is the only browser having problems with it.

Comment: Definitely seems like firefox bug. Did you report this to firefox team? Is it acceptable to use javascript for this? It works OK if you wait until the scaled image is rendered, then you measure the height, then change height from 100% to the measured amount. Make that a function to run on initial load and also on resize and boom.. firefix for ya

Comment: @nothingisnecessary I'll see where I can report it, hopefully there'll be a fix to it. It wouldn't be a problem using JavaScript (as I am using it for other functionality already), but I'd rather not. I've currently implemented a background-image solution zer00ne put me on to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

This second version, Demo 2, has been stripped of all flex, `fixed` position, and even intrinsic measurements (`vw`). Firefox works and even IE surprisingly.
Changed the background-color to make it look spacier.

## Major Changes

- Added `html,body {height:100%;width:100%}`
- `.wrapper` needed 100x100% as well.
- Now `.image` and `.text` has a parent that their percentages can relate to.
- Gave `.image` `min-height:100%`
- Removed both `<img>` and used `background-image`

### Optional Changes

- Made `.wrapper` `position:fixed`
- Made `.text` and `.image` `position:absolute`
- `.wrapper` is a flex container
- `.wrapper` has `overflow-y:scroll` so at smaller widths, text can still be read and it's `scroll` instead of `auto` so there be no jumpy behavior when the scrollbar pops in and out.
- I also edited Marv as a PNG with a transparent background. P38 modulator not included.

### Demo 1

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 49vw;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  word-break: break-word;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.image {
  min-width: 49vw;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: url("https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/saturn.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.marv {
  background: url("https://image.ibb.co/h1pCQy/marv.png");
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vel enim vulputate, luctus dolor vel, efficitur ante. Maecenas eget massa eu mi varius posuere vel mattis ante. Cras non fermentum sapien. Nunc sollicitudin nisi a posuere commodo. Fusce
        tincidunt mi velit, in hendrerit dolor cursus et. Nam laoreet laoreet varius. Aliquam ut elit at elit ultricies iaculis vitae at purus. Pellentesque massa mi, ultricies elementum consequat sit amet, aliquam vitae sem. Nulla tempus nec augue non
        lacinia. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed quis rhoncus urna, lobortis bibendum sapien. Morbi accumsan commodo malesuada. Praesent porta tortor sed tristique dignissim. Maecenas et urna sit amet tortor semper commodo at vitae lectus. Nullam
        imperdiet viverra sem, pellentesque sagittis ipsum pellentesque a. Mauris rutrum nunc id lectus commodo rhoncus.</p>

      <p>Etiam mollis massa id lorem rhoncus venenatis. Donec lacinia orci lacus, ac auctor augue vehicula vitae. Cras dignissim, augue vitae hendrerit cursus, enim velit lacinia tellus, sit amet sollicitudin dui mauris eget tortor. Donec eu nulla a est
        interdum aliquet. Praesent et lectus interdum, malesuada felis sed, sagittis est. Pellentesque in accumsan diam. Nam tristique porttitor tortor. In rutrum tellus nisi, id condimentum tellus fringilla ut.</p>
      <p>Etiam mollis massa id lorem rhoncus venenatis. Donec lacinia orci lacus, ac auctor augue vehicula vitae. Cras dignissim, augue vitae hendrerit cursus, enim velit lacinia tellus, sit amet sollicitudin dui mauris eget tortor. Donec eu nulla a est
        interdum aliquet. Praesent et lectus interdum, malesuada felis sed, sagittis est. Pellentesque in accumsan diam. Nam tristique porttitor tortor. In rutrum tellus nisi, id condimentum tellus fringilla ut.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <div class='marv'></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

### Demo 2

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 50%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  word-break: break-word;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.image {
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: url("https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/saturn.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.marv {
  background: url("https://image.ibb.co/hioYDJ/marv.png");
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vel enim vulputate, luctus dolor vel, efficitur ante. Maecenas eget massa eu mi varius posuere vel mattis ante. Cras non fermentum sapien. Nunc sollicitudin nisi a posuere commodo. Fusce
        tincidunt mi velit, in hendrerit dolor cursus et. Nam laoreet laoreet varius. Aliquam ut elit at elit ultricies iaculis vitae at purus. Pellentesque massa mi, ultricies elementum consequat sit amet, aliquam vitae sem. Nulla tempus nec augue non
        lacinia. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed quis rhoncus urna, lobortis bibendum sapien. Morbi accumsan commodo malesuada. Praesent porta tortor sed tristique dignissim. Maecenas et urna sit amet tortor semper commodo at vitae lectus. Nullam
        imperdiet viverra sem, pellentesque sagittis ipsum pellentesque a. Mauris rutrum nunc id lectus commodo rhoncus.</p>

      <p>Etiam mollis massa id lorem rhoncus venenatis. Donec lacinia orci lacus, ac auctor augue vehicula vitae. Cras dignissim, augue vitae hendrerit cursus, enim velit lacinia tellus, sit amet sollicitudin dui mauris eget tortor. Donec eu nulla a est
        interdum aliquet. Praesent et lectus interdum, malesuada felis sed, sagittis est. Pellentesque in accumsan diam. Nam tristique porttitor tortor. In rutrum tellus nisi, id condimentum tellus fringilla ut.</p>
      <p>Etiam mollis massa id lorem rhoncus venenatis. Donec lacinia orci lacus, ac auctor augue vehicula vitae. Cras dignissim, augue vitae hendrerit cursus, enim velit lacinia tellus, sit amet sollicitudin dui mauris eget tortor. Donec eu nulla a est
        interdum aliquet. Praesent et lectus interdum, malesuada felis sed, sagittis est. Pellentesque in accumsan diam. Nam tristique porttitor tortor. In rutrum tellus nisi, id condimentum tellus fringilla ut.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <div class='marv'></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your expansive suggestion. Unfortunately I have some boundaries I have to work within. The .wrapper div is one element in the page layout, there are more (variable) elements surrounding it. Using position:fixed would be difficult in this scenario. I have tried the display: flex solution while trying @G-Cyr 's suggestion, but as I've said there, I need Internet Explorer to work as well. And seeing as Firefox is the only browser (that I've tested with) that doesn't work as expected, I'm more inclined to drop the second graphic in this browser.

Comment: There are 2 lists. First one is titled "Major Changes", the second one is titled "Optional". The `fixed` position and `flexbox` is in the "Optional" list. Is Marv the second Graphic? BTW, the `fixed` element is higher up on the hierarchy, it's not as invasive as you think it is, regardless it's optional. 
My main point is that using a `min-height:100%` should resolve your issue.

Comment: @Vivienne ok, there's a very compatible, responsive version see Demo 2.

Comment: I decided to use the background-image solution you came up with. Of course I'd rather Firefox played nice, but this is a decent compromise. Thanks for the idea, the bounty is yours :)

Comment: You are very welcome and thanks. Firefox used to be my favorite browser for years, now I am beginning to despise it like IE. -_-

Answer (score 2):

It has to be a bug on firefox. Your code seems to be working under 1170px. So I have come up with a quick fix, I don't know whether it's applicable in your case or not.

CSS:

```css
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }


.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1170px;

  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.text {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.image div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image div:after {
  content: url("https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/6/67/Marvin_the_martian.jpg");
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
}

.image>div>img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
.big-wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

}
```

```html
<body class="big-wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="text">
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vel enim vulputate, luctus dolor vel, efficitur ante. Maecenas eget massa eu mi varius posuere vel mattis ante. Cras non fermentum sapien. Nunc sollicitudin nisi a posuere commodo. Fusce
          tincidunt mi velit, in hendrerit dolor cursus et. Nam laoreet laoreet varius. Aliquam ut elit at elit ultricies iaculis vitae at purus. Pellentesque massa mi, ultricies elementum consequat sit amet, aliquam vitae sem. Nulla tempus nec augue non
          lacinia. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed quis rhoncus urna, lobortis bibendum sapien. Morbi accumsan commodo malesuada. Praesent porta tortor sed tristique dignissim. Maecenas et urna sit amet tortor semper commodo at vitae lectus. Nullam
          imperdiet viverra sem, pellentesque sagittis ipsum pellentesque a. Mauris rutrum nunc id lectus commodo rhoncus.</p>

        <p>Etiam mollis massa id lorem rhoncus venenatis. Donec lacinia orci lacus, ac auctor augue vehicula vitae. Cras dignissim, augue vitae hendrerit cursus, enim velit lacinia tellus, sit amet sollicitudin dui mauris eget tortor. Donec eu nulla a est interdum
          aliquet. Praesent et lectus interdum, malesuada felis sed, sagittis est. Pellentesque in accumsan diam. Nam tristique porttitor tortor. In rutrum tellus nisi, id condimentum tellus fringilla ut.</p>
        <p>Etiam mollis massa id lorem rhoncus venenatis. Donec lacinia orci lacus, ac auctor augue vehicula vitae. Cras dignissim, augue vitae hendrerit cursus, enim velit lacinia tellus, sit amet sollicitudin dui mauris eget tortor. Donec eu nulla a est interdum
          aliquet. Praesent et lectus interdum, malesuada felis sed, sagittis est. Pellentesque in accumsan diam. Nam tristique porttitor tortor. In rutrum tellus nisi, id condimentum tellus fringilla ut.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <div>
          <img src="https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/saturn.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not an option to limit the .wrapper div to a specified width. The reason it works on smaller widths is that the image then fills its 50% of the screen (because of the text taking in more vertical space and the image scaling with it). In the real world case this problem applies to, both text and image size are variable, so not something I can take as a given.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code below your CSS to fix on Firefox. But it is only true if the image does not resize in width. So you can mix with @media to use.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
        .image div {
            display: ruby-base;
        }
        .image div:after {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can refer to here: https://www.chenhuijing.com/blog/how-well-do-you-know-display/

Comment: Lol I read that right after I asked...but I didn't get how it it applies to this situation

Comment: Oh, I only suggest to fix on Firefox. Because I tested on Firefox, it runs okay. :)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this solution doesn't seem to work in this case. The 'display: ruby-base' wraps around the image correctly, and if there's enough room to show the complete image, the second image is placed nicely in the bottom right corner. When there's not enough room though, the second image disappears because the .image div doesn't scale to the available width. Working with @media to add breakpoints to shrink the image at intervals isn't an option, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code please replace image style rules as below:

```
.image > div > img {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And after rules as below:

```
.image div:after {
    content: url(https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/6/67/Marvin_the_martian.jpg);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -100px;
    right: -60px;
    /* width: 100px; */
    /* height: 120px; */
}
```

I tested in both chrome and firefox, it works.

Comment: Hi @Tapas, using width: 100% deforms the image, which isn't what I want. I don't mind part of the image disappearing behind the overflow:hidden of the containing div, but the ratio of the image needs to stay the same.